# Combine two statements with LIMITS using UNION

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way to combine these two statements into one without having duplicate entries?

```
SELECT * FROM Seq where JULIANDAY('2012-05-25 19:02:00')<=JULIANDAY(TimeP) 
         order by TimeP limit 50

SELECT * FROM Seq where JULIANDAY('2012-05-29 06:20:50')<=JULIANDAY(TimeI)  
         order by TimeI limit 50
```

My first, obvious attempt is not supported by `SQLITE` (Syntax error: Limit clause should come after UNION not before):

```
SELECT * FROM Seq where JULIANDAY('2012-05-25 19:02:00')<=JULIANDAY(TimeP) 
         order by TimeP limit 50
UNION
SELECT * FROM Seq where JULIANDAY('2012-05-29 06:20:50')<=JULIANDAY(TimeI)
         order by TimeI limit 50
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use subqueries and perform the limit within them.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  * 
            FROM    Seq 
            WHERE   JULIANDAY('2012-05-25 19:02:00') <= JULIANDAY(TimeP) 
            ORDER BY TimeP
            LIMIT 50
        )
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  * 
            FROM    Seq 
            WHERE   JULIANDAY('2012-05-29 06:20:50') <= JULIANDAY(TimeI) 
            ORDER BY TimeI
            LIMIT 50
        )
```

Answer (score 9):

Queries are processed in stages:

1. `FROM` clause and all the joins;
2. `WHERE` clause and all the predicates. So if you whant to see `NULL` values in the result set, you should never filter `OUTER`-joined table columns in the `WHERE` section, as this will turn your query into `INNER` join;
3. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause;
4. Query combinations: `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT` or `MINUS`
5. `ORDER BY`
6. `LIMIT`

Therefore, as others pointed out, it is syntatically wrong to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` *before* `UNION` clause. You should use subqueries:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Seq
         WHERE JULIANDAY('2012-05-25 19:02:00') <= JULIANDAY(TimeP) 
         ORDER BY TimeP LIMIT 50) AS tab1
UNION
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Seq
         WHERE JULIANDAY('2012-05-29 06:20:50') <= JULIANDAY(TimeI)  
         ORDER BY TimeI LIMIT 50) AS tab2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from
    (SELECT *
    FROM Seq
    where JULIANDAY('2012-05-25 19:02:00')<=JULIANDAY(TimeP)
    order by TimeP limit 50)
UNION
SELECT * from
    (SELECT *
    FROM Seq
    where JULIANDAY('2012-05-29 06:20:50')<=JULIANDAY(TimeI)
    order by TimeI limit 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a table `buysell_product`. I want to select top 5 based on `views_1` column and another top 5 using `views_2` column, then merge the two. Columns are the same in both queries. Expecting this to work, it does not:

```
SELECT id, name, views_1, views_2
    FROM buysell_product
    ORDER BY views_1 DESC
    LIMIT 5
UNION
SELECT id, name, views, views_2
    FROM buysell_product as b
    ORDER BY views_2 DESC
    LIMIT 5
```

Error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before
At line 1:
...
```

They work separately but I need to merge them:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, views_1, views_2, name
    FROM buysell_product
    ORDER BY views_1 DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, views_1, views_2, name
    FROM buysell_product as b
    ORDER BY views_2 DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
```

Result:

| id | views_1 | views_2 | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 41 | 16 | Excellent 2013 ford ecosport |
| 3 | 72 | 10 | Excellent Hyundai creta |
| 5 | 39 | 39 | iPhone 11 128gb |
| 7 | 12 | 84 | Excellent Hyundai creta sx |
| 9 | 37 | 84 | Volkswagen Polo 1.2 GT AMT 2017 |
| 44 | 34 | 81 | Usupso Massage Anti Skid Slippers |
| 45 | 15 | 75 | Garlic Powder - 100Gm |
| 57 | 35 | 11 | Iphone 13 and 14 |
| 67 | 15 | 73 | Universal Touch Screen Capacitive Stylus |